# yii2 identity $authKey return array

Tags: php, yii2

I am using `yii2`. When a user logs in through identity checkout, I myself create a token, write it myself in cookies and in the database. So that a user can log in from multiple devices, a single user can have many tokens in the database.

When I have not visited the site for a long time, the session and cookies die and an error appears, converting the $ authKey array to a string. It occurs in the class `yii \ web \ User`.

```
protected function getIdentityAndDurationFromCookie(){
    $value = Yii::$app->getRequest()->getCookies()->getValue($this->identityCookie['name']);
    if ($value === null) {
        return null;
    }
    $data = json_decode($value, true);
    if (is_array($data) && count($data) == 3) {
        list($id, $authKey, $duration) = $data;
        /* @var $class IdentityInterface */
        $class = $this->identityClass;
        $identity = $class::findIdentity($id);
        if ($identity !== null) {
            if (!$identity instanceof IdentityInterface) {
                throw new InvalidValueException("$class::findIdentity() must return an object implementing IdentityInterface.");
            } elseif (!$identity->validateAuthKey($authKey)) {
                ERROR HERE:   Yii::warning("Invalid auth key attempted for user '$id': $authKey", __METHOD__);
            } else {
                return ['identity' => $identity, 'duration' => $duration];
            }
        }
    }
    $this->removeIdentityCookie();
    return null;
}
```

my validateAuthKey in Models\User

```
public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
{
    $tokenArray = $this->getAuthKey();
    foreach($tokenArray as $item){
        if ($item->Token === $authKey){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

In this method, all tokens are taken from the database for this user and a match is searched

I displayed `$authKey` in `yii\web\User` and got an incomprehensible array. Array has 30 empty objects.
Why is $ authKey composed of an array?

As I understand it, it should contain only 1 token I need, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem probably is that your `getAuthKey()` implementation returns array. The `yii\web\IdentityInterface` expects the `getAuthKey()` to return string. [See documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-identityinterface#getAuthKey()-detail)